# UITableView: how to resize header containing word-wrapped label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableheader

The header in my `UITableView` contains a word-wrapped label which can have variable text, spanning from 0 to 4 lines.

for this reason, I cannot really determine upfront the header height with this function:

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {`

Is is possible somehow to let the header resize on its own?

Answer (score 3):

### Autoresizing

If you're using auto-layout, you can create autoresizing cells/headers/footers for `UITableView` like this:

**Cells**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Headers**

```
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 68.0
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Footers**

```
tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 68.0
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

You can also use the `UITableViewDelegate` method, `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection` if you'd like to dynamically calculate the estimated height. For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let calculatedHeight = estimatedHeaderHeightCalculator(section: section)
        return calculatedHeight
  }
```

---

### Calculated

I usually skip autoresizing and calculate the size of the cell manually. Autoresizing cells on the fly is finicky and spending my day changing hugging/compression constraints is my idea of hell.

If you know the string in question, calculate the size like this:

```
extension: String {

    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height
    }

}
```

Then in your `UITableViewDelegateMethod`:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let constrainingWidth = tableView.bounds.width
        let font = UIFont(name: "YourHeaderLabelFont", size: 16)!

        let headerString = yourHeaderString
        let heightForString = headerString.heightWithConstrainedWidth(constrainingWidth, font: font)

        return heightForString
    }
```

Note that the calculated height is **only** for the string and you will probably need to add some padding.